# Can I use IntellijJ during plugin installation?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ.

I got used to installing plugins and continuing development in the meantime.

But when I clicked "OK" during the installation, the application asks me if I want to restart it to apply plugin changes. When I click "yes" and restart, I can see that the plugin is still not installed (so I guess the installation was just interrupted).

Do I need to wait till the plugin is installed to continue work?
The window beneath "Settings" seems to be not active.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, IntelliJ 2018.3.4 community edition.

Comment: Restart button should be active only after plugin installation. Probably there is some other issue that prevents plugin loading at startup. Is it possible to attach idea.log ("Help | Show log in...") and name plugin you installed?

Comment: It's not a problem with a plugin, when I waited till it finish installation and then restarted, it worked fine.
I used active then "OK" button from settings dialog. Then IntelliJ asked me if I want to restart (I believe it shouldn't if the installation is not complete), and I clicked "yes".
And after restarting the plugin was not installed. But then I tried to install it again, waited and everything was ok.